# Python[2.7] - Subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make a script to accelerate testing.

I have my program "foo" which returns a series of commands and "bar" which control those commands.

foo is executed as follow :

```
./foo ARG(1) ARG(2) ARG(n)
```

bar is executed with the same argumets :

```
./bar ARG(1) ARG(2) ARG(n)
```

And then waits for a series of commands given manually or by foo output.

Thus, I use my programs that way :

```
./foo ARG(1) ARG(2) ARG(n) | ./bar ARG(1) ARG(2) ARG(n)
```

I am trying to replicate the pipe behavior in python :
lst is a liste of my ARG()

```
output = subprocess.check_output([os.path.realpath("foo")] + lst)
res = subprocess.check_output([os.path.realpath("bar")] + lst, output)
```

Obviously, it is not the right method but I have been trying multiple ways and it is not working.

Comment: See [`subprocess` documentation - Replacing shell pipelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline)

Comment: Pease have a look into this useful library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh

Answer (score 0):

I handled all bash commands in a project by **[sh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh)** library.

You can easily handle all of your commands like so:

```
import sh
sh.grep(sh.cat('/etc/passwd'), '-i', 'my_username')
```

Please have a look into FAQ of *sh* library: http://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/faq.html